# python ieee keywords extra

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want `s` to be a dictionary, then I can choose the information I need, I try your code I have a 7862 link need to find the keyword and doi but this 7862 link I tried and found that some will not get the information I want And report an error, so how do you go about this situation?? Here is my complete code.

I think I found the focus of it. This is a regular expression error. He refers to the matching part. There is no exact match. For example, this can match

> https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8479309

, but this doesn't work

> https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8613142

code is here

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import random
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import time

ieee_content = requests.get(link, timeout=180)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ieee_content.text, 'xml')
tag = soup.find_all('script')

try:
    metadata = "".join(re.findall('global.document.metadata=(.*)', tag[9].text)).replace(
                    ";", '').replace('global.document.metadata=', '')
    data = json.loads(metadata)
    print('!')
except :
    print('!@!@')
try:
   doi = 'https://doi.org/' + ''.join(data['doi'])
   links.append(doi)
except:
   pass

try:
    keywords = data["keywords"][0]['kwd']
except:
    keywords = []
try:
    date = datetime.strptime(data["journalDisplayDateOfPublication"], "%d %B %Y")
except:
    pass

es.update(index='item', doc_type='ieee', id=esid,
         body={'doc': {'links': links, 'keywords': keywords, "published": date}},
                           request_timeout=1900)

print('upload %s' % esid)
```

Comment: I can not get this code to run. What is `es`, `esid` and `links`?

Comment: es is Elasticsearch esid is Elasticsearch data id links is ieee links mark es and esid then u can run

Comment: Figbeam  u can try it with this two links 1.https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8479309   2.https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8613142

Comment: change `xml` in `soup = BeautifulSoup(ieee_content.text, 'xml')` to `lxml` and let me know if this helped. I think you are having issues dealing with some non-unicode data in the file.

Comment: OMG it working!!! thank u very much